# How to reload a specific DIV Element with the help of button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom-events

I am having 3 components in my HTML code. 2 DIV tags and 1 Button. I want the First DIV Tag to reload on the button click. I have applied the jQuery but nothing is happening on the button click. 
Here is my HTML code embedded with the JS code as well.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--Font Awesome Icons-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>DIV Load Testing</title>

</head>

<body>

    <button id="reloader" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left"></i> Reload
    </button>
    <!--DIV TAG TO BE RELOADED ON THE BUTTON CLICK-->
    <div class="container" id="content">
        <h1>Reloads</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

        <img src="colorizer-desktop.PNG">

        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
<!---->

    <div class="container">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <img src="image-desktop.PNG">
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#reloader').click(function(){
               // alert('ok');
                $('#content').load(' #content');
            });
        });

        //function myButton() {
        //    location.reload();
        // }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have used 2 scenarios:

1. With the help of jQuery.
2. With the help of `location.reload();` function.

By the `location.reload()` function, the whole page is reloading but I want only the first DIV Tag to be reloaded on the click of the button.

Kindly help in this functionality!

Comment: what do you mean by div reloading?

Comment: So what do you expect `reload` to do?

Comment: What do you mean by reloading a div element?

Comment: Why you have different jQuery versions loaded.. Bootstrap's JavaScript requires at least jQuery v1.9.1..

Comment: DIV reloading means that to refresh the contents of the DIV element by clicking the button @MayankPatel

Comment: Yeah, but what will be the updated content for `div`? Do you want to update anything in div content?

Comment: I have written different jquery version just to have the functionality done @DeDav

Comment: why would you include jquery 4 times in 3 different versions

Comment: No, I just want to reload or refresh the first DIV Element contents by clicking the button @MayankPatel

Comment: @Dipanshu the contents can not come out of nowhere, where is the content located?

Comment: @Dipanshu Put this inside your `click` handler: `$('#content').text('<b>Some</b> new content.');`

Comment: When you say reload, you can update the content of Div. For ex. you can change text, add image, etc. Just reload will not perform any action for `div`.

Comment: @Dipanshu you keep providing the same answer that is not an answer to the question. You cannot reload or refresh the content of a DIV unless the content is changed in some way, and you have the original content stored someplace. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [jQuery .load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/):

> The `.load()` method, unlike `$.get()`, allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.
>
> We could modify the example above to use only part of the document that is fetched:
>
> `$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );`
>
> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of `ajax/test.html`, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded.
>
> jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by `.load()` may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

So your script should be like the following:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#reloader').click(function() {
    var self = window.location.href;
    console.log("Loading '#content' from " + self);
    $('#content').load(self + ' #content');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="reloader" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left"></i> Reload</button>
<div class="container" id="content">
  <h1>Reloads</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

  <img src="colorizer-desktop.PNG">

  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Note: *This snippet will not work in this environment and would need to be tested in your own code.*

Comment: Hi @Twisty Thanks for the answer. please let me know where I have to write the <script> files. Inside the head tag or at the bottom of the HTML tag
Files are below:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Many thanks your code is somewhat wroking I just need to paste the above file.

Comment: @Dipanshu thats your choice to store the `<script>` content in the head or at the bottom of the body.

Answer (score -2):

I have no idea what you mean by "reload the div". What do you expect to happen?

Apart from that, the jQuery .load() function is used to load a remote file from the server and display its content. You need to tell the function which file it has to load:

```
$('#content').load('sample.html');
```

So, if your html file with the Javascript function is named index.html, your call would be:

```
$('#content').load('index.html #content');
```

This will tell your function that it has to load the div #content from file index.html.

Comment: Hi @toneyt thanks for the comment. "Reload the div' simply means refreshing or reloading the content of the div element by clicking the button without refreshing or reloading the entire page. I have included the index.html file as mentioned by you but the DIV Element is not reloading or refreshing.

Thanks!!

Comment: Well, if your div did not change between loading the page and clicking the button, the div might have been reloaded but you will not see any difference.